# Ambiguity regarding $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})$

Tags: complex-numbers, extension-field

I am studying field theory.I found a question in Artin's algebra which asks if $i\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})$.Now I am confused  with the meaning of $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ here because there are $4$ of them.It is not specified which one I should take.So,I am having problem.Can someone please help me?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(i)/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois so it doesn't depend on the choice of $\sqrt[4]{-2}$.

Comment: Any root of $x^4+2$ can be chosen, and you get an isomorphic field. This is true for $x^4+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x].$ This is because the field is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^4+2\rangle.$ So usually, we don’t care which one. If there is an element I. If there is an element in one field with $u^2=-1,$ there is an element in the others, too. Then either $u=i$ or $-u=i,$ and $i$ is in all the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t matter which root you choose. $i$ is in one $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]{-2}]$ if and only if it is in all of them.

If $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x],$ and $\alpha$ is a root, then $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle.$ So any other root $\beta$ of $p(x)$ has $\mathbb Q[\beta]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[\alpha],$ since both fields are isomorphic t9 the quotient field.

This means, given $q(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$ with a root in $\mathbb Q[\alpha],$ there is also a root of $q(x)$ in any $\mathbb Q[\beta]$ where $\beta$ is another root of $p(x).$

Now, $i$ exists in a subfield  $K\subseteq\mathbb C$  if an only of $q(x)=x^2+1$ has a root in the field. This is because a root is either $i$ or $-i,$ and if $-i\in K,$ the. $i\in K.$

So what this means is that it doesn’t matter which $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ you use. $i$ is in one if and only if it is in all.

This isn’t always true - it depends on properties of $q.$ But it is always true for $q(x)$ rational and quadratic - that if one root of $q(x)$ is in $K,$ then all roots of $q(x)$ are in $K.$

You are right to ask, though.

An example where this doesn’t work is $p(x)=x^8+9$ and $q(x)=x^4+9.$ We know that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[8]{-9}]$ will contain some complex root of $q(x),$ but which one will depend on which complex value $\sqrt[8]{-9}$ we choose.

Answer (score 3):

This answer has many similarities to that of Oscar Lanzi, but I thought a bit more detail might be helpful.

---

It is true that for each root of $\mu^4+2=0$, $\mathbb{Q}[\mu]$ is a different ring, but all four of these rings are isomorphic.

Suppose $\mu^4+2=0$ and $i\in\mathbb{Q}[\mu]$. That is, we have $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\left(a\mu^3+b\mu^2+c\mu+d\right)^2+1\\
&=\underbrace{2(ad{+}bc)\vphantom{\left(a^2\right)}}_0\,\mu^3-\underbrace{\left(2a^2{-}2bd{-}c^2\right)}_0\,\mu^2-\underbrace{2(2ab{-}cd)\vphantom{\left(a^2\right)}}_0\,\mu+\underbrace{\left(d^2{-}2b^2{-}4ac{+}1\right)}_0\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Since $x^4+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (via [Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)), $\left\{1,\mu,\mu^2,\mu^3\right\}$ are independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, each of the coefficients in $(1)$ must be $0$.

Since $ad+bc=0$ and $2ab-cd=0$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=2(ad+bc)^2+(2ab-cd)^2\\
&=\left(2a^2+c^2\right)\left(2b^2+d^2\right)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
That is, $a=c=0$ or $b=d=0$.

If $a=c=0$, then $2a^2-2bd-c^2=0\implies b=0$ or $d=0$.
$\quad$if $b=0$, then $d^2-2b^2-4ac+1=0\implies d^2+1=0\quad\Rightarrow\Leftarrow\tag3$
$\quad$if $d=0$, then $d^2-2b^2-4ac+1=0\implies2b^2=1\quad\Rightarrow\Leftarrow\tag4$

If $b=d=0$, then $2a^2-2bd-c^2=0\implies2a^2=c^2\quad\Rightarrow\Leftarrow\tag5$

Cases $(4)$ and $(5)$ rely on the irrationality of $\sqrt2$.

Cases $(3)$-$(5)$ are exhaustive; thus, $i\not\in\mathbb{Q}[\mu]$.

Since we only used that $\mu^4+2=0$, this works for any root: $\mu=\frac{\pm1\pm i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

The four distinct roots of $x^{4}+2$ are given by:-

$$\sqrt[4]{-2}=\sqrt[4]{2}\exp(\dfrac{(2k+1)i\pi}{4})\,,k=0,1,2,3$$.

For $k=0$ we have

$\sqrt[4]{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))=\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})$

For $k=1$

$\sqrt[4]{2}(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4}))=\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})$

For $k=2$.

$\sqrt[4]{2}(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{4}))=\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}})$

For $k=3$

$\sqrt[4]{2}(\cos(\frac{7\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{7\pi}{4}))=\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}})$

Say I pick $k=0$ and denote $\sqrt[4]{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))=\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})=\sqrt[4]{-2}$ for the rest of the answer.

Suppose $i\in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})}$.

Then $\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}),i\in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})}$

So taking their product we have

So $\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})} $

Then their $\frac{\text{difference}}{2} =\sqrt[4]{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})}\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{-2})}$.

Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})$ and it is evident from the expression $\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})$ that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$.

So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})$.

But this gives a contradiction since $[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{2},i):Q]}=8$ but
$[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[4]{-2}):Q]}=4$ as the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ is given by $x^{4}+2$. So $i$ does not belong to the $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-2})$

So in the proof you can clearly see that it does not depend on the $k$ chosen as you will end up picking a $-$ or a $+$ sign in the real or imaginary parts in the expression
$\sqrt[4]{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}})$ . The crux of the argument is that the moment $i$ lies in the field it becomes the splitting field of $x^{4}+2$ and also the splitting field of $x^{4}-2$ which should be a degree $8$ extension and not degree $4$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron can you provide the explicit roots of the equation?

Comment: @Dovahkiin Thanks I have edited.

Comment: $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ is used throughout the post, meaning a specific number, which makes it a bit confusing. It might be clearer to choose a $\mu=\frac{\pm1\pm i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$ and use that throughout.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick. The splitting fields of $x^4-2$ and $x^4+2$ are same and you are implicitly using the idea $i\notin\mathbb {Q} (2^{1/4})$ (probably based on notion that the field involved consists of real numbers). However note that a simple algebraic proof of $i\notin \mathbb {Q} (2^{1/4})$ requires an argument similar to those given in robjohn's or Oscar Lanzi's answers.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Thanks for the comment. My attempt was to provide a solution using less computation and yeah for that we have to make the compromise of taking $i$ to be a complex number for granted or the fact that $x^{2}+1$ has no roots in $\Bbb{R}$ .

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a confusing case; choosing different fourth roots of  $-2$ will in fact give different extensions of $\mathbb Q$. Of course the extensions would be the same if the primitive ratio of the roots, $i$, were in the field ... so I've given the answer away!

In fact there is a simple proof that $i$ will not belong in the field. Since the generator is a fourth-degree algebraic number, any element in $\mathbb Q[r]$ where $r$ is any fourth root of $-2$ must have the form

$a+br+cr^2+dr^3; a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R.$

We then seek a solution to the equation

$(a+br+cr^2+dr^3)^2=-1.$

We expand the square and equate the linearly independent (over the rationals) components:

$r^0: a^2-4bd-2c^2=-1$

$r^1: 2ab-4cd=0$

$r^2: 2ac+b^2-4bd-2d^2=0$

$r^3: 2ad+2bc=0.$

Now solve the $r^1$ and $r^3$ equations for $d$. This gives

$d=ab/2c=-bc/a,$

from which either $b=0$ or $a/2c=-c/a$. The latter possibility fails by inconsistent signs for all nonzero rational numbers $a$ and $c$, so $b$ is forced to zero. Similarly, solving the $r^1$ and $r^3$ equations for $b$ leads to $d=0$.

Then with $b=d=0$ the $r^2$ equation forces either $a=0$ or $c=0$, neither of which then admits a rational solution for the $r^0$ equation. So $\mathbb Q[r]$ with $r^4=-2$ cannot contain a square root of $-1$.

The reader should explore what happens if $-1$ is replaced by a general rational number $q$. Intuitively we might expect the above contradiction to kill the proposition unless $q$ is either a rational square or $-2$ times a rational square. Is that result actually obtained?

> Yes, the only rational numbers whose square roots lie in $\mathbb Q[r]$ are as given in the last paragraph.

Comment: The other answer does not contradict your one as you claim in your 2nd paragraph. Can you please explain how the four roots of the other answer are incorrect?.

Comment: So is the other answer correct or wrong?.

Comment: Please sir, I am trying to learn field theory and I do not understand what is supposed to be wrong in that answer . The roots of the polynomial are unique and the four roots Gandalf provided are first of all distinct and all of them satisfy the equation. Your method uses the explicit basis and is really good but it requires a  lot of computation. But the other answer seems correct to me. Can you please tell me where the ambiguity lies ? .

Comment: (+1) I have posted a late answer that is along the same lines as yours. I hope that it supplies some extra detail, but If you think it is too close, I will delete it.